# How can I tell definitively, for a given browser, which elements supports which events?

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-events

I was trying to figure out why my onblur and onfocus wasn't working on a TD in Chrome. After some research and experimentation where I found conflicting info from different web sources, it seems that TD doesn't support onblur and onfocus.

So, in general, to save time and trouble, it would be good to know for sure on a given browser which (element, event) pairs are supported. Is there a place where this is conveniently listed?

I could do my own experiments, but if it the event is not triggering, who knows, it could be not triggering for other unknown reasons, not because it's unsupported by the element.

Does using jQuery make this any easier? I notice that even the jQuery documentation doesn't say which elements are supported:
http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Answer (score 1):

You can check here : [Events compatibilty](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/)

W3 also has detailed documentation about the events. You can refer to [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-types)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you may have seen in the "List of DOM3 Event Types" section in [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-types), all `Element`s support blur event. The problem of focus-related events is that some elements are not focusable by default, i.e. you can't navigate to them using the `Tab` key. Actually, only few elements (mainly input elements) are focusable by default.

So, can we change this default behavior? Yes, we can use `tabIndex` attribute on elements we them to have focus. You can find my sample HTML page here: http://martianboy.handcraft.com/focusEvents

All `td` elements are focusable there.